# Ajax post json to service using php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using jquery to post data to server using ajax and php.

This is client code:

```
var serverService="http://localhost/service/";
var base_url = serverService+'doing.php';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "user": "test",
                "type": "type 1"
            }),
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

And this is server:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$result = array();
if(isset($data['user']) && isset($data['type'])){
  //do something
}
else{
  $result['error'] = "fail";
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

When posting, server not recognize user and type, show it's allway return `fail` .

Please help me!

Comment: what is serverService here?

Comment: `var serverService="http://localhost/service/"` I'm include index.js, it work because it return '$result'. But i will edit my post. tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need you add your data like describe below.

**FROM**

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                "user": "test",
                "type": "type 1"
            }),
```

**TO**

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                user: "test",
                type: "type 1"
            }),
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Yes, it's work, ~^^~, my wrong, it's so crazy ^^, thank you!

Comment: @CaoHữuThànhHuy: Glad to help you out from this hurdle.